# RabbitMQ Go tutorial log.Printf can't write to disk file?

Tags: macos, go, rabbitmq, command

I'm following the RabbitMQ tutorial via go. Here is the link: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-go.html

when I run the following command to log message to file:

```
go run receive_logs_direct.go warning error>logs_from_rabbit.log
```

But the logs_from_rabbit.log file  still empty.

[image]

What's wrong with it?

Comment: What are you expecting in `logs_from_rabbit.log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your redirect is missing logs from the standard error output.

Try:

```
go run receive_logs_direct.go warning error >stdout.log 2>stderr.log
```

Or:

```
go run receive_logs_direct.go warning error 2>&1 >full.log
```